# Convert Date to UTC DateTime

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat, localtime

I have the date 2023-04-03 and wanted to convert it into UTC time with range (start and end of the day)

2023-04-03T00:00:00 -> 2023-04-02T18:30:00z
2023-04-03T24:00:00 -> 2023-04-03T18:30:00z

Input: 2023-04-03
Need this output: 2023-04-02T06:30:00z, 2023-04-03T18:30:00z

I have tried LocalDate and SimpleDateFormatter, but they are not converting to this way.

```java
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDate.parse("2023-04-03").atStartOfDay();
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
System.out.println(":inst: " + instant.toString());
```

output of the above code:

Hello: 2016-06-12T00:00

:inst: 2016-06-12T00:00:00Z

Comment: I suppose that `2023-04-02T06:30:00z` is a typo on your part and you want 6:30 PM AKA 18:30. Can you confirm or deny, please?

Comment: Though not the same you may find this question and its answers helpful: [Start and End of Week w/ ThreeTenBackport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56742948/start-and-end-of-week-w-threetenbackport)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried LocalDate and SimpleDateFormatter, but they are not converting to this way.

### Stop using the error-prone legacy date-time API

The `java.util` date-time API and their corresponding parsing/formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) was released as part of the **Java 8 standard library** which supplanted the legacy date-time API and since then it is strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

### You need a time zone to get the desired output

Your desired output (**start and end of the day**) is in UTC and therefore you need to convert the date-time from your time zone to UTC. Once you have **start and end of the day** in your time zone, you can convert them to UTC using [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-).

**Demo:**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zoneIndia = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2023-04-03");

        System.out.println(date.atStartOfDay(zoneIndia)
                .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));

        System.out.println(date.atStartOfDay(zoneIndia).with(LocalTime.MAX)
                .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));

        // Or get the exlusive upper range (half-open interval for the day)
        System.out.println(date.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(zoneIndia)
                .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2023-04-02T18:30Z
2023-04-03T18:29:59.999999999Z
2023-04-03T18:30Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/3VJoA1)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Ditto Thanks for the feedback, @OleV.V. I thought the same but changed my answer before posting it. I should have kept both the inclusive and exclusive upper range. I have done it now.

Comment: While there is good information and suggestions in all the other answers, this is the one that is to the point and shows exactly how to do the conversions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:

```java
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2023-04-03");
ZonedDateTime startOfDay = localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime endOfDay = localDate.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault());

System.out.println(startOfDay.toInstant() + ", " + endOfDay.toInstant());
```

---

**Explanation:**

With this Line

```java
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

You configure the time you created in the LocalDateTime at the Zone UTC.

I assume you (or your system) are not at UTC-Time so you need to define the `ZonedDateTime` at your `ZoneId` like this:

```java
ZonedDateTime startOfDay = localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault());
```

If you want to define your `ZoneID` not from your system you can do something like this (IST for example):

```java
ZonedDateTime startOfDay = localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.of(ZoneId.SHORT_IDS.get("IST")));
```

Comment: I suggest you skip the needless involvement of a `LocalDateTime`. Just pass the `ZoneId` to `atStartOfDay` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

## Skip `LocaDateTime`

No need to involve a `LocalDateTime`. That class cannot represent a point on the timeline. Its usage here only confuses things.

```
LocalDate               // Represent a date-only value. No time of day. No time zone or offset. 
.parse( "2023-04-03" )  // Parse text in standard ISO 8601 format. Returns a `LocalDate` object. 
.atStartOfDay(          // Let java.time determine the first moment of the day. While the day always starts at 00:00 in UTC, that is not always the case in some time zones on some dates. 
    ZoneOffset.UTC      // A constant, representing an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. 
)                       // Returns a `ZonedDateTime`. 
.toInstant()            // Adjusts to an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes by converting to `Instant`. 
.toString()             // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

Comment: The question asked for `2023-04-02T18:30:00z`, and the OP is located in Pune, India. When I run your code with Asa/Kolkata as default time zone, I get `2023-04-03T00:00:00Z`, so not exactly what was asked for. Still upvoted for the good information and suggestions in the answer.